# Node.js applies the changes only after restart

Tags: node.js, express, nuxt.js, serverside-javascript

I am very new to server side scripting. And I am using NodeJS. My Problem is that after adding some new features to the app, i.e. after changing the code, these changes will be applied only after restarting the server. Till then NodeJS behaves so as though I hadn't changed anything. So for instance if I add `console.log("works")` and don't restart the server, then it hasn't any effect.

I am using Nuxt.js, which is actually the Vue.js framework but with additional and very usefull features mainly for server side rendering. I didn't integrate the express.js at the beginning of the project, beacause it wasn't planned to write any server side code. So I am normally exporting express and using it, which is pretty fine for me, since I need just a couple lines of code to use the NodeJS file system.

So, as it is pretty hard to code, if I should restart the server once I changed anything, I want to ask you if there is any solution to this problem.

Comment: This is expected behavior. You can use `nodemon` https://nodemon.io/ to watch over your files and restart the server once your file has been changed.

Comment: @maksbd19 thats not really expected behaviour. nuxt have build monitor with webpack HMR for dev mode

Answer (score 1):

Use [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon)

step 1 : npm install -g nodemon <- this will install nodemon globaly in your system

step 2 : change your start script within package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "nodemon fileName" <- like this //filename is you root file which starts the app like app.js
}
```

step 3 : npm start

Comment: "start": "nodemon server.js" or "start": "nodemon app.js"

Comment: depends what you have named you file : like "nodemon anyName.js".

Comment: Well I have already `"start":"nuxt start"` in my `"scripts"` and I added `nodemon` like `"start":"nodemon nuxt start"`, but it didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: no, you have to mention fileName you want to start like :"nodemon fileName.js" .
remove nuxt from "nodemon nuxt start" and replace start with fileNam.js

Comment: Give "nuxt start server.js" or "nuxt start app.js"

Answer (score 0):

This is already build in into nuxt. You just need to run it in dev mode, not in production.
E.g. for dev with change monitoring

```
nuxt
```

For production without monitoring

```
nuxt start
```

Answer (score 0):

So in this particular case the following changes to the `"scripts"` in `package.json` have solved my problem.

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon --watch api --exec \"nuxt\"",
    "start": "nodemon nuxt",
  }
```

The following [link](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1819) could also be usefull to you.

Answer (score 0):

Install nodemmon in your application to allow live update `npm -g install nodemon`

and add the following codes inside your packages json file :

```
 "main": "app.js",


"scripts": {
"start": "node app"


},
```

on your command line, just type : start